# Solver for Min Cost Flow with Concave Cost Function

Tags: optimization, graph, graph-algorithm

Is there any solver available to handle **Minimum Cost Flow Problem with Concave Cost Functions**? Can the problem be converted to any other well-known network optimization model that might be more controllable?

(Please comment on the asymptotic complexity if any known)

Comment: I would look at solving as a MIP using piecewise linear approximations.

Comment: That'd definitely work. However, not using the structure as a network optimization model could cost an exponential running time rather than a polynomial one.

Comment: Well, it is a non-convex problem.